Next.js Socket Implementation (import issue likely)
I've set up a websocket under src/socket-server/index.js
const { Server } = require('socket.io');

let io;

module.exports.emitSocketEvent = (event, data) => {
  if (!io) {
    console.log('Socket server not started');
    return;
  }
  io.emit(event, data);
};

module.exports.startServer = () => {
  if (io) {
    return io;
  }

  console.log('Starting Socket server');

  var server = http.createServer();
  io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: '*', // Allow all origins
      methods: ['GET', 'POST'], // Allow GET and POST methods
      allowedHeaders: ['my-custom-header'], // Allow specific custom headers
      credentials: true, // Allow credentials
    },
  });

  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log('user disconnected');
    });
  });

  server.listen(3333, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3333');
  });

  return io;
};

And I'm calling startSever in next.config.js like so
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'wwgkpxkfgqjhcgrevcps.supabase.co',
      },
    ],
  },
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (isServer) {
      const { startServer } = require('./src/socket-server/index.js');
      startServer();
    }
    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;

At this point client is successfully connecting to the websocket server.
However the io instance is still null whenever I try to call emitSocketEvent in src/actions/create-message.ts. I assume this an issue with how importing the files
'use server';

import { createClient } from '@/src/utils/supabase/server';
import { generateResponse } from '@/src/doula';
import { createConversationSummary } from '@/src/actions';
import { emitSocketEvent } from '@/src/socket-server/index.js';


export const createMessage = async ({
  content,
  conversationId,
}: {
  content: string;
  conversationId: string;
}) => {
  const supabase = createClient();
  const {
    data: { user },
  } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

  if (!user) {
    throw new Error('User not found');
  }

  const response = await generateResponse({
    content,
    userId: user.id,
    conversationId,
  });

 

  // console.log('io ///////', io);

  emitSocketEvent('message', response);

 
};


